# PXE booting from iSCSI disk stucking on logo

Tags: windows-10, pxe, iscsi, wds, syslinux

I have win srv 2012 r2 with WDS, TFTP and iSCSI target. Goal is to boot lite win10 with rdp to use it for RDS. WDS configured with syslinux and it working. On boot i can see PXE vesamenu.c32, then choose submenu to loading from iSCSI. On remote disk installed win10 with WinNTSetup. When i try to booting all works done, iPXE working and iSCSI target initing, but when i see Win logo its stucking. Virtual machine working on Hyper-V. If iSCSI isn't inited, booting from cd/dvd stucking on logo too, but if i directly booting from drive it working fine.

sysLinux 3.86 version

```
win10.ipxe:
#!ipxe
dhcp net0
set keep-san 1
#login
sanboot iscsi:10.10.10.10::::iqn.xxx

pxeLinux.cfg\default:
DEFAULT vesamenu.c32
#---
LABEL WDS
MENU LABEL WDS
KERNEL pxeboot.0
#---
LABEL Windows 10 64bit
MENU LABEL Win10load
MENU DEFAULT
KERNEL IPXE.LKRN
INITRD win10.ipxe
#---
LABEL Reboot
MENU LABEL Reboot
KERNEL reboot.c32
```

i tried to change win10 image, and no one from custom or official doesn't work with similar result. Tried to off set keep-san because i think its stucking process, for now i have no ideas.